# Show My Instagram Photos in My Website

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Assume I have an Instagram account and a website. I want to display the most recent photos from my Instagram account on website. Something I am not clear in the documentation: in order to get my `access_token` I need to authenticate myself? I don't get how to do it in backend side. It works fine if I logged in as my account, but in incognito, there is a dialog pops up asking username and password. I don't want user to see that.

Do I need to provide my username and password in backend side and auto login? and I don't want to see the pop up dialog asking authentication. I need everything handled in backend side. How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can authenticate and get your `access_token` using the client implicit Oauth, you just have to open the auth url:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token
```

setup a `redirect-uri` in your app settings, it can be `http://localhost` too.

opening above url in browser will show login page, once u login, you will be redirected to your the `redirect-uri`, the `access_token` will be in the `redirect-uri`:

```
http://localhost#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

copy the `access_token`

You can then make API call to get your own latest 20 photos and display on your website:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

You dont need to be approved by instagram, u can remain in sandbox mode and get latest 20 pics via API.

Comment: ahh... anyway I can avoid login page? it requires user (or my) personal interaction with instagram. And I need to do that everytime `access_token` expires, right?

Comment: just do it once manually to get your access_token, and then use that in the website to load photos.

Comment: It won't expire in the future?

Comment: does not expire. in some cases it may expire if u request password reset or something like that, in that case you have to get new and update access_token, I have had the same access_token that worked for years